# Uploading an image from asp.NET (C#) to Oracle 11g

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle11g

I would like to upload an image from an asp.NET Web Forms (4.0) application to an Oracle 11g database. Eventually, I would also need to retrieve the image.

I was told to use a blob type, but this can change if a better solution is found.

From the front end perspective I am using the asp.NET File Upload component and is great to select the path of the file.

What is the best way around it? Work with blob's? work with bfile's? upload the image on the server and just store the path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have a table called IMAGES with a BLOB column, you'll want to do something similar to:

```
byte[] imageData = FileUpload1.FileBytes;

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO IMAGES(PARENT_ID, IMAGE_DATA) VALUES(:1, :2)", connection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleDbType.Int32, parentID, ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleDbType.Blob, imageData, ParameterDirection.Input);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

**Update**:
When it comes to display the image, you mainly need to understand that the HTML page only contains a reference to the image (`<img src="ImageFromDatabase.ashx?id=1234">`) and that the image itself is served by a separate request. The following example uses a *Generic Handler*:

```
public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    HttpRequest request = context.Request;
    int parentID = Int32.Parse(request.QueryString["id"]);

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("SELECT * FROM IMAGES WHERE PARENT_ID = :1", connection);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleDbType.Int32, parentID, ParameterDirection.Input);
    OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    byte[] imageData = ((OracleBlob)reader["IMAGE_DATA"]).Value;
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageByte);
}
```

I've omitted all the error handling which you should be added in a real application.

**Update 2:**

If you have a grid view, you could define the image column like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# "ImageFromDatabase.ashx?id=" + Eval("ImageID")%>'/>
```

Comment: thanks you helped me in implementing this functionality, was thinking it was more complicated. Is it that simple to show the images too?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out a simple way how to show items in a grid view? do you have an idea?

Comment: I've added some code for displaying the image (see my answer above).

Comment: Would this still work in a grid view? Can it not be bound using the <%# Eval("image") %>? I am also unsure how this will work: src="ImageFromDatabase.ashx?id=1234" since I would imagine I need to bind them all manually.

Comment: Would I need to create an ashx file with your ProcessRequest method?

Comment: Yes, part of my proposed approach is to create a Generic Handler in a ashx file.

Comment: Sorry, I understood much more now. These .ashx are new for me. I just need to figure out how that image url calls on my .ashx file I created.

Comment: @RyanSammut: I've added a small sample for how to use the image in a grid view (see my answer).

Comment: Thanks very much, this works. Is there a way to get it accept all types of files, being jpeg's and png's?

Comment: I noticed this has problems when uploading files larger than 4kb, it only stores part of it. Have you ever encountered this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Best would be to upload the image on the server and store the path.

Why you ask?

1. Modern day OSses have fast file-system so fetching a image would be fast, much faster than serving from a DB.
2. You will add undue stress to your database if you store the image in the database.
3. Since the images are on the file system you can simply use path, instead of a service to serve images.

Comment: That was my thought initially, however I would prefer if it was on the database for backup purposes. Other than that, I agree with you on all points. What do you think?

Comment: Why not do both? Save the image in the database but serve them from the file system.

Comment: Very good point, given the time, I would have done this. I had already done the part where it uploads to the server. However, I stopped there once I got it working through binary data, since it was preferred from my seniors.